# Calculator from Google Forms Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am newbee in google apps script. So I learned how to code some functions in Sheets. But may Google Form use data from Sheet with answers? So I think to create calculator.
When I debug code in script in "Sheet with answers from Form" everything works fine. But I don't know how this script become workable when I create this code in script in the Form.
Please help me.
I want that after user press button "Send form" he get browser window with value from cell from "the Sheet with answers from the Form".

My code:

```js
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Ответы на форму (1)");
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var cols = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Лист4");
  var values = sheet2.getRange(rows, cols+1, 1, 1).getValue();
  Browser.msgBox("Your value: " + values + " $");  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work since the onFormSubmit trigger runs as you and not the user submitting the form. The only way of doing something like this is to build a custom form in apps script.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is not possible at the moment using Google Forms.

There is currently no way of issuing a dynamic response to the form user.

If you are still interested in the possibility of doing such a thing, I suggest you check out Google Apps Script [WebApps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), that will allow you to implement this functionality (although will also require more work).

The idea is that:

- You create an HTML form that can be retrieved from the Browser through the `doGet()` function.
- The form submits a POST request with all the user's data, which is handled by the `doPost()` function. This function inserts the data into your Sheets document by means of the `SpreadsheetApp` class, and returns an HTML response containing the response value.